# Examples of simple non-parallelizable smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm looking for examples of simple non-parallelizable smooth manifolds and honestly just general insight into the concept of a manifold being parallelizable.

$S^2$ would be parallelizable, right? At each point on $S^2$, you can have two vectors meet orthogonally that are tangent to $S^2$, and would thus span the tangent space at that point.

It seems to me that if you have an $n$ dimensional smooth manifold, that if you can find $n$ linearly independent vector fields, (so that at each point on the manifold, $V_1(x),....,V_n(x)$ are linearly independent)$, Then your manifold would be parallelizable.

General insight and comments greatly appreciated!

Comment: The point is a *global* one. Locally, you can always find $n$ linearly independent vector fields. Indeed, on $S^2$, you cannot even find *one* nowhere-vanishing vector field. Interestingly, though $S^1\times S^2$ *is* parallelizable.  Can you find three everywhere linearly independent vector fields in that case?

Comment: Hmm, I can not. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Start with the standard orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^3$ and for each vector, create a vector field on $S^1\times S^2$ by projecting onto the tangent space of $S^2$ and using what's "left over" to get a vector tangent to $S^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S^2$ is *not* parallelizable.  This fact is famously known as the [Hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).

On any coordinate patch $U$ with coordinates $(x^1, x^2, \dots, x^n)$, the vector fields $V_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ are linearly independent.  But when you cover a manifold with multiple coordinate patches, there may not be a way to extend those vector fields to the entire manifold and keep them linearly independent (or nonzero).